# Scala: How to set a keyword as a method name

Tags: scala

I want to use a keyword `for` as a method name.

```
object Fun extends App {
  def just = this
  def for (a: Any) = this // error
  def fun = this

  just for fun
}
```

But get an error:

```
Error:(11, 7) identifier expected but 'for' found.
  def for (a: Any) = this
      ^
```

Is it possible to do it in `Scala` somehow?

Comment: There is the difference between "possible" and "a good idea" to keep in mind.

Comment: I've just heard that Scala has very powerful implicit mechanism which could do a real magic :) So why not? Maybe it is easy to overload  a keyword.

Answer (score 3):

backticks escape everything.

```
def `for`(a: Any) = this
```

Comment: But is it possible to write an expression without the single quotes? `just for fun`? I don't think so.

Comment: @barbara It's not possible.